# Bash/Linux - Group Every 5 Lines, Compare Groups to Check for Duplicates

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file which has information grouped by every 5 lines.  Every 5th line is a new group.  I need to check for duplicate information.  The comparison cannot be done by just the group name but all 5/5 lines must match.  I've experimented with placing each group into a new column and would then perform a field comparison using AWK.  I'd then also have to reformat the file to the original. All of that seems ugly. Are there are any better ideas and code samples?

Current Code (half completed):

```
awk -v n=5 '{ c++ } c>n { c=1 } { a[c] = (a[c] ? a[c] FS : "") $0 } END { for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[i] }' file
```

Below is my file:

```
Group1
    646
    123
    143
    174
Group2
    231
    542
    456
    182
Group3
    879
    14
    5676
    414
Group1
    646
    123
    143
    174
Group4
    969
    106
    591
    5961
Group3
    879
    14
    5676
    414
Group2
    8256
    56
    266
    254
```

Below is the desired output (notice that there are two "Group2" names but the values are different):

```
Group1
    646
    123
    143
    174
Group2
    231
    542
    456
    182
Group3
    879
    14
    5676
    414
Group4
    969
    106
    591
    5961
Group2
    8256
    56
    266
    254
```

**#########   Edit   ###############**

Sorry...None of the solutions are working on my actual file.  I tried a simplified file format.  Let me share a portion of it, because it is extremely long.

Below is a portion of my actual file:

```
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^3-A-2-O1_ATLNGAMQO1ZSADDTNINF^1-A-1-O1 */
ALPSGA_ATLNGA_0 {
    srlg-value 1000;
    srlg-cost 10000;
}
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^3-A-2-O1_MACNGAHRO1ZRDCDTNINF^1-A-1-O1 */
ALPSGA_MACNGA_0 {
    srlg-value 2000;
    srlg-cost 10000;
}
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^1-A-1-O1_NSVNTNJYO1ZILADTNINF^2-A-2-O1 */
ALPSGA_NSVNTN_0 {
    srlg-value 3000;
    srlg-cost 10000;
}
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^1-A-2-O1_NSVNTNJYO1ZILADTNINF^2-A-1-O1 */
ALPSGA_NSVNTN_10 {
    srlg-value 4000;
    srlg-cost 10000;

/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^3-A-2-O1_ATLNGAMQO1ZSADDTNINF^1-A-1-O1 */
ALPSGA_ATLNGA_0 {
    srlg-value 1000;
    srlg-cost 10000;
}
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^3-A-2-O1_MACNGAHRO1ZRDCDTNINF^1-A-1-O1 */
ALPSGA_MACNGA_0 {
    srlg-value 2000;
    srlg-cost 10000;
}
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^1-A-1-O1_NSVNTNJYO1ZILADTNINF^2-A-2-O1 */
ALPSGA_NSVNTN_0 {
    srlg-value 3000;
    srlg-cost 10000;
}
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^1-A-2-O1_NSVNTNJYO1ZILADTNINF^2-A-1-O1 */
ALPSGA_NSVNTN_10 {
    srlg-value 4000;
    srlg-cost 10000;
}
/* SNBRCATCO1ZILADTNINF^3-A-1-O1_SNJYCAHMO1ZEQUDTNINF^3-A-1-O1 */
SNBRCA_SNJYCA_0 {
    srlg-value 85000;
    srlg-cost 10000;
}
```

Desired output:

```
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^3-A-2-O1_ATLNGAMQO1ZSADDTNINF^1-A-1-O1 */
ALPSGA_ATLNGA_0 {
    srlg-value 1000;
    srlg-cost 10000;
}
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^3-A-2-O1_MACNGAHRO1ZRDCDTNINF^1-A-1-O1 */
ALPSGA_MACNGA_0 {
    srlg-value 2000;
    srlg-cost 10000;
}
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^1-A-1-O1_NSVNTNJYO1ZILADTNINF^2-A-2-O1 */
ALPSGA_NSVNTN_0 {
    srlg-value 3000;
    srlg-cost 10000;
}
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^1-A-2-O1_NSVNTNJYO1ZILADTNINF^2-A-1-O1 */
ALPSGA_NSVNTN_10 {
    srlg-value 4000;
    srlg-cost 10000;
}
/* SNBRCATCO1ZILADTNINF^3-A-1-O1_SNJYCAHMO1ZEQUDTNINF^3-A-1-O1 */
SNBRCA_SNJYCA_0 {
    srlg-value 85000;
    srlg-cost 10000;
}
```

Comment: are you missing `}` in your example file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `gawk` (GNU `awk`)...

**EDITED** for the updated data set

```
$ awk -v RS='/\\*' -v ORS='' '!a[$0]++{print rt $0} {rt=RT}' file
```

similar change will work with the other scripts

Comment: @shaikisiegal why do you think so?  This uses **record** structure 
 which `awk` supports and compares the full record, instead of line.

Comment: sorry , my mistake :( you are right :),  nice solution :)

Answer (score 1):

This `gnu-awk` may work for you with custom `RS`:

```
awk -v RS='Group[0-9]+' '!seen[h $0]++{print h $0} RT{h=RT}' ORS= file
```

```
Group1
    646
    123
    143
    174
Group2
    231
    542
    456
    182
Group3
    879
    14
    5676
    414
Group4
    969
    106
    591
    5961
Group2
    8256
    56
    266
    254
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, but the order will not be maintained

```
paste -d " "  - - - - -  < file1 | sort -u | awk '{print $1 "\n\t" $2 "\n\t" $3 "\n\t" $4 "\n\t" $5}'
```

EDIT - as per the new file, you can try this.

```
paste -d "\t"  - - - - -  < file2 | sort -u | awk -F'\t' '{print $1 "\n" $2 "\n" $3 "\n" $4 "\n" $5}'
```